# Why any quasi modular form corresponds to some almost holomorphic form?

Tags: modular-forms

I am trying to understand this article.

http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0603268v1.pdf

In particular Theorem 1. In particular it says that if

$$
(c z + d)^{-k} f_0(\frac{a z + b} {c z +  d})
= \sum_{j = 0}^{p} f_j(z) (\frac{c} {c z + d})^j$$

Then 
$$
(c z + d)^{-k + 2 l} f_l( \frac{a z + b} {c z + d})
 = \sum_{j \geq l} \binom{j} {l} f_j(z) (\frac{c} 
{c z + d})^{j - l}$$

First equation is special case $l=0$.

**Question**: How to prove this?

Comment:
Author give link to this article, but I did not find a proof.
http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/progmath/129/165/fulltext.pdf

Answer (score 1):

By definition, quasi-modular forms are constant terms of almost holomorphic modular forms w.r.t. $y={\rm Im}(\tau)$ expansion.
Therefore, the map $\sum_{i=0}^n f_i(\tau) y^{-i} \rightarrow f_0(\tau)$ is 
surjective. Proof of injectivity can be found in this paper

http://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9712009.pdf

(see Proposition 3.4)

Comment: Not quite. The definition 1 in http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0603268v1.pdf is different. It says just that there are $f_j$ (with some condition). But it does not say that "quasi-modular forms are constant terms of almost holomorphic modular forms".

Comment: Theorem 1 (in the same paper) tells you that two definitions are equivalent (see the last sentence).

Comment: Of course it does. But there is no proof. And I did not find link to proof.